# How to retrieve data sent from jquery.get in python flask

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, flask, get

```
$.get( "/check", { name: $("#value").val() }, function (data){
      if(data){
//do something
      }
      else if(data){
//do something
        });
      }
    });
```

how do I access this name variable in the flask route defined as follows

```
@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check():
//method body
return jsonify(//some boolean variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access parameters to the request using the 'args' dict in the request object.

```
from flask import (Flask, request)

@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check():
    return "You wrote" + request.args['name']
```

Comment: writing request.args['name'] gives an error in the code.

Comment: Did you do "from flask import request"? What's the error message?